# Save state of String within EditText and clear string within same button

Tags: android

I was wandering if there is anyway to save a String from an EditText and clear it within the same onClick button.

The reason is I am creating a jumble word game where 1 player can jumble a word and then clear the word so the 2nd player cannot see it. The reason why I want to save the String is so I can match it with what player 2 enters.

Any advise would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following fragments of code in your onClick:

```
// Save
String text = someEditText.getText();
// Clear:
someEditText.setText("");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this but then how can I access String text from another method which will check if the answer matches String text?

Comment: I'd need to see some code to give you a correct answer for that.  Add it to your question if you can.  The most likely answer is going to be set the `otherString` to be final (if possible) and then just call `stringInOnClick.equals(otherString);`

Comment: Thanks for your help and your time, I managed to sort this out. Thanks again